# All the complex polynomials $p$ and $q$ for which $p(z)\sin^2(z)+q(z)\cos^2(z)=1$ holds.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the complex polynomials $p$ and $q$ for which $$p(z)\sin^2(z)+q(z)\cos^2(z)=1$$ holds.
We know that the function $\sin^2(z)+\cos^2(z)-1$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and bounded, so it is constant. And since this function in $0$ on real line, $$\sin^2(z)+\cos^2(z)-1=0 \text{  on  } \mathbb{C}$$ But I have no idea for the polynomials $p$ and $q$ other than $1$. Please help me to find all such complex polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that the above holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_1=p-1$, $q_1=q-1$, then $q_1(z)\cos^2(z)+p_1(z)\sin^2(z)=0$.

Now take $z=k\pi$, $k$ an integer, then $q_1(z)=0$. Thus $q_1$ has infinitely many roots so is zero. Similarly, $p_1=0$, hence $p=q=1$.